# R returns an error when I ask for "fiw %>% count(Country/Territory)"

Tags: r

I'm trying to use "count()" to explore the variable "Count/Territory" from the data base "fiw". Why it returns an error?

I'm triying writing it like this:

```
fiw %>%
  count(Country/Territory)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column name is unusual because of the presence of `/`.  Can backquote it and get it working

```
library(dplyr)
fiw %>%
   count(`Country/Territory`)
```

Comment: Now I see where was the mistake,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main cause of the error is the black slash `/`. In R to divide one column by another you can use `/`. For example if you need to divide the data in column A by the data in column B you can write `A/B`.